# redirecting the output of a python command to a txt file working in cmd but not in .bat file, how to solve?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

well I'm trying to make a logger for my python script using a runner in a '.bat' format, that executes the script and saves an output file; without me having to do it manually.

when I tried to run my python script, script.py, and pass 20 as an argument for the script as well as redirecting the output to a log_file.txt, using windows command prompt, it worked just fine, and the log file was created.
~the cmd command:

```
python script.py 20 >> log_file.txt
```

But when I tried to run the same code using the runner ".bat" file it didn't work.

~The codes I've written inside the "runner.bat" is as follows

```
python script.py 20 >> log_file.txt
pause
```

~but the execution command is done by the bat file was-as seen from the screen-:

```
C:\Users\dahom\Desktop\folder>python script.py  1>>log_file.txt
```

I expected the ".bat" file to behave the same save the log_file as the cmd terminal.
But when I ran the bat file it didn't redirect the output to the log_file.txt
But it seems to be running the script, without but one indication that it takes some time for the script running.
note: both the batch file and the script are in the same folder/dir/path.

[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Cf2.jpg) is an image showing everything.

Comment: You might need a full path of your Python PAT_TO_HERE/python.exe PATH_TO_HERE/script.py

Comment: I don't think so, the cmd and the bat file are both running from the same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY:**

```
@echo off
 "C:\Users\dahom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "C:\Users\dahom\Desktop\new.py" >> "C:\Users\dahom\Desktop\log_file.txt" & type "C:\Users\dahom\Desktop\log_file.txt" 
pause
```

**NEW.py:-**

```
print("Echo Fox")
```

**OUTPUT OF THE BATCH SCRIPT:-**

```
Echo fox
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**WORKING:-**

Just Provide the full paths of each file used in the command `(python exec, python script, text file etc)`. When the command get's pipe'd to file use `& type "file_path"` to display the contents of the file after writing it.

Comment: if your batch script in is the different directory then your python file, then you have to first change the `CWD` of command prompt, to the directory in which your python file exists, by using `cd "Dir_of_python_file"`. This isn't necessary but still if your python file requires a lot of external modules it may create some error's if you not do so.

Comment: didn't work, both the script and the batch file are in the same folder.
That is what showed up:
C:\Users\dahom\Desktop\folder>"c:\Users\dahom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "script.py" 20  1>>log_file.txt

C:\Users\dahom\Desktop\folder>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: i don't want you to use the path that i gave to you for your python interpreter, rather choose your's. Just open IDLE and click open file location to get the path and copy it as the first parameter to the command and see if it works?

Comment: it happens to be the same as mine. python 3.7.0

Comment: is the file getting created?

Comment: try using full paths in batch scripting from later on, as in commandline everything is almost context sensitive, one thing may work at a certain place, but the same thing may not work at the other, so it is generally advised to use full paths, wherever possible.